# to_erl program output

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

When I try to connect to an Erlang shell using the following command:

```
to_erl /tmp/erlang.pipe.1
```

The output of the command is something like this:

```
Attaching to /tmp/erlang.pipe.1 (^D to exit)

(search)`':     
(node@mypc)1>
```

What is that "(search)`':"?

I use the following command to start the Erlang node to attach to:

```
run_erl -daemon /tmp/ /tmp "erl -sname node"
```

Comment: I do not see the `(search)`':` string. Could it be from your shell (bash)?

Comment: No I think it is from Erlang shell, but I don't know what is that. It was not like this before, but today it prints that.

Comment: What version of Erlang are you running?

Comment: @Lukas could it be from the new search facility in the shell in R16?

Comment: @Lukas I am using R16A.

Comment: @coffeMug When i do you the commands as you write, but i meet an error `to_erl: command not found`. Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: @coffeMug I have resolved my problems. The command `to_erl` is in this path `/usr/lib/erlang/bin`. When i use this full path like this `/usr/lib/erlang/bin/to_erl /tmp/erlang.pipe.1`, it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the shell search history mentioned in item OTP-10739 [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/notes.html#id79834). I think this should be considered a bug and be reported as such to the erlang-patches mailinglist.